# DispatchQueue not working in while loop

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, while-loop, nstimer

[image: Screen capture of frozen screen]

***Edit:*** I once I restarted the computer and tried the simulator agian terminal displayed the message, Terminal has detected that the system is running low on swap space. Scrollback buffers may automatically be timmed to conserve swap space. I am not sure what to make of this message.

Prior to posting this question I wanted to ask for a method to display 3 successive images. I settled on

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
    self.icon1.isHidden = false
}   // display image after 3 sec
```

I used this method of delaying the the execution of the code for showing and hiding all the images by changing the length of the delay.

This works fine when the "start" button is pressed but when I tried to create a while loop, the simulator freezes when I press the start button

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func start(_ sender: Any) {
    var x = Int(0)

    repeat {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + stepperval.value/4) {
            self.icon1.isHidden = false
        }

        // stepperval is the current value of the UIStepper

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + stepperval.value/4*2) {
            self.icon2.isHidden = false
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + stepperval.value/4*3) {
            self.icon3.isHidden = false
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + stepperval.value) {
            self.icon1.isHidden = true
            self.icon2.isHidden = true
            self.icon3.isHidden = true

            self.direction.isHidden = false
            self.direction.image = self.derection[Int(arc4random_uniform(4))]
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + stepperval.value*2) {
            self.direction.isHidden = true

            x = x+1
        }
    } while x < Int(4) //Loop 4 times
}
```

Once the start button is pressed icon1,2,3 
are supposed to appear eatch image after a certian inteval, 
then hide once again followed by the image 
'direction' appearing. Then loop 4 times.

Comment: Did you try to pause the execution and see which line causes the freeze?

Comment: I once I restarted the computer and tried the simulator agian terminal displayed the message, Terminal has detected that the system is running low on swap space. Scrollback buffers may automatically be timmed to conserve swap space. I am not sure what to make of this message.